# Is it possible for a websocket frame to fail to arrive?

Tags: websocket

As I understand it, Websockets use a Ping to detect that they are still connected.  Except of course Chrome which leaves it to apps to do the ping themselves.

I'd like to understand if its possible for a connection to become unstable between pings such that a frame of data is not received... but to stabilize again by the time the next ping is sent.  In other words: is it possible to have an apparently good websocket connection, but for data to fail to arrive?

Question relates to [Is it possible to miss websocket events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922073/is-it-possible-to-miss-websocket-events) which remains unanswered and side-tracked into long-polling and socket-io.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is heavily dependent on the client software (browser) that you use.

The websockets depend on a TCP connection which will make sure the message arrives to destination. Except if the network connection is down, of course.

However, some clients (browsers) will suspend the inactive tabs and will not process the events. If your page is inactive, it "may" fail to send data to the server because it will not be executed at all. On the other hand, it "may" also fail to receive data because the handler will not be executed at all.

Meanwhile, even if inactive, the machine will still receive the ping packets. So it is really about whether or not your client software gives it back to your code or not.